# Upload and tag video to facebook

Tags: video, facebook

Is it possible (using the native facebook app) to upload a video and tag it?

I know they recently included the ability to tag people in photos, but I'm not sure if you can do it to videos as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can tag the videos themselves. You cannot actually view them in the native app either, when viewing it takes you to a video player of your choice.

As far as creating a post with a video and tagging a post I am not sure about.

Hope this helps.